# Want to find the way to generate the thumbnail image for a given pdf file

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm

I'm currently looking for a way to generate the thumbnail image for a given pdf file, which shows several pages in the same image. The output should like what shows in the [arxiv sanity](http://www.arxiv-sanity.com) website. I want to know if there is any `npm` package which supports this functionality. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery / javascript PDF Thumbnail creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687584/jquery-javascript-pdf-thumbnail-creation)

Comment: @HarshaW Thank you for your quick response. The link you gave to me only shows the method that uses the first page of the pdf file to generate the thumbnail image, however, what I want is to show at most 8 pages in the same image. The task is little different, but anyway, thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

```
var PDFImage = require("pdf-image").PDFImage; //pdf to image convert

var pdfImage = new PDFImage("1120.pdf");
  pdfImage.convertPage(0).then(function (imagePath) {
},(err)=>{
   console.log("err",err)
})
```

//##jimp Npm use thumbnail image generate

//if auth error Follow this step :
-> In /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml (or /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml) find the following line
-> 
and change it to allow reading and writing by the PDF coder in ImageMagick:

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick command line, you can do that as follows. Suppose you want 8 pages from the PDF.

Input PDF from http://www.arxiv-sanity.com:

```
convert image.pdf[0-7] -thumbnail 140x140 -background white +smush 20 -bordercolor white -border 10 result.jpg
```

[image]

This takes the first 8 pages, makes thumbnails of size 140x140 and appends them side-by-side with a 20 pixels white spacing between them and adds a 10 pixel white border around it all.

Sorry, I do not know Node.js. But apparently there is a module that integrates ImageMagick. See https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick